# Android shapes and drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I'm wondering if I get an image from somewhere and layers to it.

For example:

I have this Drawable object which contains my Facebook profile picture. I have another Drawable object which is a bit bigger, and it is supposed to be a frame for my profile picture. How can I programmaticly add these two layers to one Drawable object?

#### Frame:

[Frame http://site.pelecode.co.il/profile/background.png](http://site.pelecode.co.il/profile/background.png)

#### Profile picture:

[Frame http://site.pelecode.co.il/profile/profile.jpg](http://site.pelecode.co.il/profile/profile.jpg)

#### Together:

[Frame http://site.pelecode.co.il/profile/together.png](http://site.pelecode.co.il/profile/together.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:src="@drawable/content" />
```

The padding is your frame

Comment: but how can i do it programaticly? not in advance.. im downloading a profile picture and save it in a drawable object and then i want to add the frame. i cant defined it in advanced

Comment: `setImageDrawable(yourDrawableObject)` for the drawable and `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourFrameImg)` for the frame

Comment: and if i don't want it inside an image view ? i just want to create a new drawable object which contains both of the drawables images ?